# Couchbase Installation on Windows 8.1

Tags: couchbase

I just installed Couchbase Server 3.0.2 on Windows 8.1. The Installation went through successfully but I am unable to access http://localhost:8091/index.html.

"Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down or your network may not be properly configured."

I tried to check if anything listening on that port using the command.

```
netstat -an -p tcp
```

But found nothing is listening on that port and the closest port i found was 8092, so thought may port has changed so when i try to browse on that port i got a json response as below.

```
{"code":404,"status":"fail","message":"controller_not_provided","ResultDate":"2015-02-06T17:13:23.2551859Z","Progress":-1,"Result":"No controller provided."}
```

Answer (score -1):

please check the couchbase service form the windows control panel. sometimes it will not start the service automatically ,it may be manual. start the service manually , if not started then check the localhost url.

you can also start the service form the desktop icon. double click on the couchbase icon it will start the service automatically and it will open the url in your default browser.

if still facing the problem not able to start the couchbase server , follow the 
.[link](http://javaant.com/couchbase/#.VQreaGSUc5R)
it describe each and every steps of the couch base installation  process.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference so your answer stays valid if the link at some point stops being valid.